# Get parent category id from child category page for custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy, terms

I have created the custom taxonomy for categories. I want to list the child categories lists of current parent category in child page.

```
$cateID = get_queried_object_id();    
$args = array(
  'format' => 'name',
  'separator' => ' ',
  'link' => false,
  'inclusive' => true
);
$checkparent =  get_term_parents_list( 
 $cateID, 'my-taxonamy' , $args
);
```

I have tried the above code. But the code returns the parent category name/link. Any way to get the parent category id in child category page? Any methods or hooks are there in wordpress for getting the parent category id?

Example case:

1. Parent category1

   - Child category1
   - Child category1
   - Child category3
2. Parent category1

   - Child category1
   - Child category1

If i am in **child category1** page, want to list the below categories.

- Child category1
- Child category1
- Child category3

Problem:
I cannot able to get the parent category id from the child category.

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a taxonomy archive page, be it for a child or parent term, you can get the current/*queried* term object/data using [`get_queried_object()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object/) which contains properties like `term_id` (the term ID) and `slug` (the term slug). And the property name for the ID of the parent term is `parent`. So you can do so to get the parent's term ID:

```php
$cat = get_queried_object();
$parent_cat_id = $cat->parent;
```

And for displaying a list of terms in the parent term, you can use [`wp_list_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/). Here's an example with the `title_li` set to `''` and `echo` set to `0`, which means I'm manually putting the output into an `UL` (`<ul></ul>`):

```php
$cat = get_queried_object();

$list = wp_list_categories( [
    'taxonomy' => $cat->taxonomy,
    'child_of' => $cat->parent,
    'title_li' => '',
    'echo'     => 0,
] );

if ( $list ) {
    echo "<ul>$list</ul>";
}
```

If you want *full control* over the HTML, e.g. to add custom HTML before/after the term link or perhaps to add custom CSS classes, you can use [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) and loop through the term objects to display the term:

```php
$cat = get_queried_object();

$cats = get_terms( [
    'taxonomy' => $cat->taxonomy,
    'child_of' => $cat->parent,
] );

if ( ! empty( $cats ) ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $cats as $cat ) {
        $url = esc_url( get_category_link( $cat ) );
        // change the 'before' and/or 'after' or whatever necessary
        echo "<li>before <a href='$url'>$cat->name</a> after</li>";
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sally. It's working. Can i able to add additional html tag to before of anchor tag?

Comment: Basically, with `wp_list_categories()`, no. But check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using a get_term function is Retrieve the terms in a given taxonomy or list of taxonomies.

Refer this Link : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/

```
     /*change on 'taxonomy'=> 'your texonomy name'*/
      $terms = get_terms(array('taxonomy'=> 'category','hide_empty' => false, ));  ?>
        <div class="category_all">
            <div class="categor">
                <?php 
                echo "<ol>";
                 //get parent category term id $term->term_id            
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    if ($term->parent == 0 ) {
                     echo "<li>";                       
                     echo $term->name; // Parent Category Name 
                         echo "<ul>";
                         $subterms = get_terms(array('taxonomy'=> 'category','hide_empty' => false,'parent'=> $term->term_id));

                        //get child category term id $value->term_id
                        foreach ($subterms as $key => $value) 
                        {
                           echo "<li>".$value->name."</li>"; // Child Category Name 
                        }
                        echo "</ul>";                       
                    echo "</li>";
                    }                   

                    }
                    echo "</ol>";
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php
```

If you want to get category term id then you can use $term->term_id in your expression

Screenshot of parent with child Category

[image]